# tkinter button not doing anything

Tags: python, tkinter

How come this isn't working? When I press the <kbd>YES</kbd> button that works, but when I press the <kbd>NO</kbd> button nothing happens.

````
def yespress(event):
    print("Yes PRESSED")

def nopress(event):
    print("No PRESSED")

## TKINTER SETUP
win = Tk()
win.title("Selector")
win.geometry('220x50')

Button_Yes = ttk.Button(win, text="YES")

Button_No = ttk.Button(win, text="NO")

Button_Yes.bind('<Button-1>', yespress)
Button_Yes.pack()
Button_No.bind('<Button-2>', nopress)
Button_No.pack()```
````

Comment: You binded to `"<Button-2>"` for the `No` button. That is the middle button on your mouse. I think you either wanted `"<Button-1>"` (left click) or `"<Button-3>"` (right click). Also instead of binding events to buttons, you can just tell the button to call your function when it's pressed using the `command` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Not with the code you are a liitlbe bit confused with the

```
widget.bind(event,handler)
```

method.

this method handle the events that occur on the widget.
in your case you are handling the single click event here

```
Button_Yes.bind('<Button-1>', yespress)
```

but what about this method

```
Button_No.bind('<Button-2>', nopress)
```

what you really want to acheive because there is no event with name
"Button-2"
the "Button-1" event is for single click event. but if you want to listen to a
double click you should use
"Double-2" not "Button-2".
I hope i answer your question.
Feel free to ask.
for more about the bind method please read this.
https://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_events_binds.php

Comment: Actually there is an event for `"<Button-2>"`. If you use the scroll wheel on your mouse to click, it will generate a `"<Button-2>"` event

Comment: Thank you for correcting me. I just have a quick look on the link mentinoed in my answer. thats why.